# Two different approaches for Key Expansion using the AES-256 algorithm?

Tags: aes, keys

I am implementing AES 256-bit Algorithm from the Theory given in the book, "Cryptography and Network Security" by Behrouz A. Forouzan.

The Algorithm described in the Book in relation to `Key Expansion`, defines `AddRoundKey` like this:

From the given 32-Bytes Cipher Key, I am supposed to generate `4 * (Nr + 1)` words. `Nr` being the number of rounds which is equal to 14 in 256bit AES and each `word` is equal to `4-Bytes`.

So, according to the equation, `4 * (Nr + 1)`, We have total `4*(15) = 60` Words to be generated. Those 60 words are `w[0],w[1],w[2],w[3],…,w[59]`. The first 8 words would be generated directly from the given 32bytes cipher key:

```
w[0] = First 4Bytes of Cipher key
w[1] = Next 4bytes of Cipher Key
w[2] = Next 4 bytes of Cipher.
…
w[7] = last 4-bytes of Cipher key.
```

The remaining words `(w[8] to w[59])` would be generated according to the following Formula:

If, `i mod 8` is not equals to `0` and `i` is the word number from 8 to 59

```
    W[i] = W[i-1] ^ W[i-8]
    ; ^ = XOR Operation
```

else

```
  W[i] = t + w[i-8]
```

where `t` equals to, `SubWord(RotateWord(W[i-1])) ^ RCon(i/4)`. If `i mod 4 = 0`, but `imod8` is not equals to `0` then, `W[i]` would be `W[i] = SubWord(W[i-1]) + W[i-8]` After the above algorithm is implemented, It is quite easy to calculate `AddRoundKey`.

But Wikipedia's ["Rijndael key schedule"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule) article has a totally different method of calculation which I am unable to understand. They use different techniques, and there are few Constants like `n` and `b`, which weren't mentioned in the book, nor are they mentioned anywhere else. Yet, Wikipedia's Algorithm is using them.

I would like to know the difference between the AES256 algorithm presented in the book and the AES256 article on Wikipedia. Can you explain and/or help me understand why there are two different approaches for Key Expansion in relation to the AES-256 algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The descriptions are the same thing.

The `n` and `b` constants on Wikipedia are simply the original key length in bytes and the number of bytes in the generated key schedule. Here, you have a 256-bit key generating a 60-word keyschedule, so `n = 32` and `b = 240`.

I'm going to re-structure the provided algorithm to be more clear. The special case `i mod 4` should be broken out as a separate block, I'll tweak the conditionals, and I'll reorder the cases to occur more sequentially.

```
if i mod 8 = 0:
    t = SubWord(RotateWord(W[i-1])) ^ RCon(i/4)
    W[i] = t + w[i-8]
else if i mod 4 = 0:
    W[i] = SubWord(W[i-1]) + W[i-8]
else
    W[i] = W[i-1] ^ W[i-8]
```

It's the same code, just written a little differently. It already looks more like the Wikipedia description.

The version here is word-based and uses the constant `8`, whereas the Wikipedia version uses byte offsets and the variable `n`, which means it takes a bit of effort to compare computed offsets between them. Just in case it isn't obvious, note that `W[i-8]` here is equivalent to the frequently used phrase "four-byte block **n** bytes before the new expanded key" on Wikipedia.

Now compare the structure:

- The first 8 words are a straight copy of the key.

  Compare Wikipedia step 1 with the initial `w[0] ... w[7]` assignment here.
- Both descriptions have a loop that generates the keys in sets of 8 words.

  This is [step 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule#Key_schedule_description) on Wikipedia. (The substeps there aren't numbered, but I'll refer to them as 3.x.)
- The first word of each set of 16 has special processing.

  Compare Wikipedia step 3.1 with the case `i mod 8 = 0` here.

  The `t` value in this step is the same as the "key schedule core" from Wikipedia. Note that the index value to `RCon` in the Key Schedule Core only increments once per loop. Here it increments 4 times per loop because it is a word-based counter, but we divide by 4 to re-normalize it.
- The next 3 words have the simple definition: XOR the previous word with the word 8 words back.

  Compare Wikipedia step 3.2 with the `else` case here.
- The next word (the fifth of the round) has special processing. Compare Wikipedia step 3.3 with the case `i mod 4 = 0` here. (Note that the `i` index here is zero-based, so `i mod 4 = 0` means we're at an index of 5.)
- The next 3 words have the same definition as two points above. Compare Wikipedia step 3.4 with the `else` case here.

That's all. They're the exact same thing, down to the step.

Comment: Where is the difference between `^` and `+` in your algorithm? Aren't they the same?

Comment: Good catch. I copied the code from the OP, I don't know why there is `+` notation. The actual algorithm uses the XOR operation, so maybe those instances should be changed to `^` for clarity. I assume they were intended to indicate the same thing.